# Create array inside array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this `result` retrieved from server side

```
this.lists = result['list_items'];
```

`result['list_items'];` contains all the elements returned from backend at a time i need only 0 index

`Output of this.lists[0]` :

```
lists: Array(1)
0:
Opt_1: "Option 1"
Opt_2: "Option 2"
Opt_3: "Option 3"
Text: "Text Message"
Status: "Active"
```

In this `0` index array i want to add one more array
i want to store `Opt_1`,`Opt_2`,`Opt_3` in an array and then place it in the same `0` index array

Resulting array should be like

```
0: 
Text: "Text Message" 
Status: "Active"
0:[
Opt_1: "Option 1",
Opt_2: "Option 2",
Opt_3: "Option 3"
]
```

Reason of creating array is because i want to create `cdkdroplist` and want to use loop through all the options.

```
<div cdkDropList #todoList="cdkDropList" [cdkDropListData]="todo" [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]" class="example-list" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
                                                <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
                                            </div>
```

Any solution, Thanks

Comment: That seems mistake prone and a pain to digest, would you rather instead do something with output more like `0:  [ Text: "Text Message", Status: "Active", Options: [ "Option1", "Option2", "Option3"]]` so it's easier to consume? Also if the option is available I'd have the backend return it in the format you desire instead of mutating it on the client side.

Comment: I agree with @ChrisW. you would want something more predictable and "typable", would you ? Avoid mutation and data manipulations if you can :)

Comment: @ChrisW. Thanks I would try to create the same structure that you provided

Comment: Re-reading my reply, I meant to say an array of objects with the value of like "options" being the array of strings. If you still want to do this on the client side I'll whip up something later if I have free time and include an interface model, have you made any attempts on your own first?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a dynamic solution, means you don't know the number of options you receive from the backend, I recommend this solution:

- remove text and status properties from the array list[0].
- set the rest of the properties into an array (the rest are the options of course)
- build a new object with array into another array with the list of options

here is [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-37zmcf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcdk-drag-drop-sorting-example.ts) for the solution I propose.

But you should know that the API response structure is too bad. the best way to go is to adjust your API response to the structure your frontend needs.